# How to access self variable array type?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, environment, self, reusability

I have defined `subnetIds` in serverless:

```
enviroment:
    subnetIds:
        - subnet1
        - subnet2
```

Now, at function define enviroment, I want to get each subnet like that:

```
environment:
       SUBNET_ID_1: ${self:enviroment.subnetIds[0]}
       SUBNET_ID_2: ${self:enviroment.subnetIds[1]}
```

I am looking for a solution that can do it.

---

Thank for support. I had found a solution to resolve it. Just define like that:

```
environment:
       SUBNET_ID_1: ${self:enviroment.subnetIds.0}
       SUBNET_ID_2: ${self:enviroment.subnetIds.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have the env variables set in the provider "environment" you do not need to assign it to each function.

```
provider:
    enviroment:
        subnet1
        subnet2
```

and use it as

```
process.env[subnet1] 
process.env[subnet2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can direct self refer from provider -> environment. But you can do it this way.

```yaml
provider:
  environment: 
    subnetIds:
      - ${self:custom.subnet1}
      - ${self:custom.subnet2}

functions:
  hello:
    environment:
      SUBNET_ID_1: ${self:custom.subnet1}
      SUBNET_ID_2: ${self:custom.subnet2}

custom:
  subnet1: "subnet1 value"
  subnet2: "subnet2 value"
```

Another thing also worth to highlight is the provider -> environment will be available in all functions by default. So you need to think again do you really need to re-declare again?